# cakephp 3 using for login another model than users auth

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to make a login from another model and I have an error.

This is my code for Student Model

```
 var $name= 'Student';

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'students',
            'action' => 'login',
            'plugin' => 'students'
        ),
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'username', //Default is 'username' in the userModel
                    'password' => 'password'  //Default is 'password' in the userModel
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

StudentsController looks like

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow('login');
} 


public function login() {

    if($this->Session->check('Auth.Student')){
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
    }


    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome, '. $this->Auth->student('username')));
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password'));
        }
    }
}
```

And the AppController is

```
 public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
}

  public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'students', 'action' => 'login'),
        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'students', 'action' => 'login'),



    ));

 public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {

    $this->Auth->authenticate=array (
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Students',
            'action' => 'login',
            'plugin' => false,
        ],
        'Basic' => ['userModel' => 'Students'],
        'Form' => ['userModel' => 'Students']
    );

}
```

And I have the following error

> Component class SessionComponent could not be found.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is `var $name= 'Student;` missing a single quote?

Comment: No, in my code it is correct.Sorry

Comment: No, in my code is var $name='Student'. I wrote wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session was deprecated in cakePHP 3, How you are doing is for cake2. In cake 3 you can use RequestHandeler like,

```
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
```

OR

```
   public $components = array(
       'RequestHandler'
   );
then use,
$this->request->Session()->read/write/delete/destroy();
```

Hope this will work for you :).

Comment: Have you removed in the 'Session' initialization from the $components. If yes, then can you say the error line no returning by Cake. @Alina

Comment: Yes. I removed and that error dissappeared. Thank you! But now, I have another error 'Call to undefined method Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent::login()'.

Comment: Add this line "$this->Auth->identify()" instead of "$this->Auth->login()" in your StudentController and login action(). --- in the if statement @Alina